# Auto post a form on page load (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, razor

I have an internal ASP.NET Core application using Razor Pages and I would like to track who and when the application is accessed.  I have a SQL table to store the values I collect. My Razor Page (partial) code is this:

```
<form method="post" name="track" id="track">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="tracking.Name" value="@User.Identity.Name" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="tracking.Time" value="@DateTime.Now" />
</form>
```

C# code behind is this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        _context.tracking.Add(tracking);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Page();
    }
```

This results in an infinite loop where the form is submitted and the page is reloaded and the form is submitted and the page reloaded......

I have tried using "onunload" and "onbeforeunload" and neither work.  Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting into a loop because you're POSTing and returning the page again. Fire and forget the request with JavaScript to an API controller. Presumably, you have a class like this:

```
public class Tracking
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

So we'll make use of that in the following controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TrackingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody] Tracking tracking)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Underneath your page, in the `.cshtml` file, add:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Notice the underscores.
            var data = {
                "name": $("#Tracking_Name").val(),
                "time": $("#Tracking_Time").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/tracking",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

If you've not setup controllers in your project yet, you'll need to call

```
services.AddControllers();
```

in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` and modify `app.UseEndpoints()` in the same file to something like:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    // Your current routes.
});
```

otherwise it won't find the controller.

One other thing: `DateTime.Now` won't be a valid JSON date, so you should either get the date on the client-side, or look at serialising it to the hidden field first. If you don't do that, the POST will fail.